# is the sql 'timestamp' column really a 'byte[]'?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

`EntityFramework` maps the SQL Server `timestamp` column to a `Byte[]` array. So for a table having a column such as `LastUpdate timestamp` the generated model property is `public byte[] LastUpdate` .

My question is how to convert this property to `DateTime` ? 
If the solution is to change timestamp into datetime, then you don't help me.

Comment: When you say timestamp, do you mean SQL Server timestamp data type?

Comment: I removed the timestamp tag as it isn't relevant (and added SQL Server!)

Comment: You can't - `timestamp` is not a date and/or time type. It's more like a unique identifier of the version of the row - it's commonly used for reliable concurrency updates, for example.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The SQL Server `TIMESTAMP` data type is not a date time value and shouldn't be confused with one. Remember that `TIMESTAMP` is a synonym for `ROWVERSION` and should be treated as such. So having it as a byte array is the best way to store it.

From the [MSDN Documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182776(v=sql.110).aspx):

> The rowversion data type is just an incrementing number and does not
>   preserve a date or a time. To record a date or time, use a datetime2
>   data type.

Comment: Thank you DavidG but you know that the timestamp is a number of milliseconds from the UNIX epoch untill now... If this is true, how do you convert this `timestamp` -> stored as `byte[]` -> to a DateTime object ?

Comment: @Bellash What makes you think that is the case? Read the doc I linked, it's all explained in there.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain The SQL standard defines a `TIMESTAMP` as date + time (so what SQL Server calls a datetime or datetime2); so in this case it is SQL Server that uses weird and confusing names.

Comment: @Bellash But what you think is totally not relevant because the TimeStamp field type in sql server does NOT CONTAIN A TIMESTMAP. It never did. It is a legacy from when this was still Sybase SQL Server. It is a counter, not a timestmap. This is VERY clear in the docuemtnation.

Comment: It's also worth noting the the `TIMESTAMP` name is deprecated in favour of calling it `ROWVERSION`

Comment: Yes. THis thing is so old - and always shows who is reading documentation and who not. Time for MS to retire it. No clue how Sybase ever came up with this idiotic name.

Comment: @TomTom I guess you could argue that the value is stamped at the time of creation/edit (tenuous I know!)

Comment: @DavidG Except that this still is not a timestamp because it does not even stamp the time into it. UpdateCounter, whatever. Any machine doing timestamps at that time (and I saw tons of them in my youth) actually stamped a date and time. So, this argument is weak ;)

Comment: @TomTom Well I didn't specify that it stamped it with the time, just that the value was STAMPed at the TIME the record was modified. Oh, and I know the argument was weak :)

Comment: @TomTom `TimeStamp` is retired. It's `RowVersion` now.

Answer (score 2):

yes it is a array of byte and no it is not a date time, if you don't like to "play" with it as an array, you can convert it to a `ulong`

```
    var timestamp = BitConverter.ToUInt64(array, 0);
```

Comment: This is correct answer. Above answer is correct as well but OP ask about solution and in my opinion this is answer for OP question.